# Output variables from remote terraform module

Tags: azure, variables, terraform, azure-rm

For a project I use remote modules (git modules) these are called and executed in a terraformMain.tf file.

For example, I use an Azure Resource Group Module, this module is looped in the terraformMain.tf by "count = length (var.resourcegroups)". The problem I have now is that I want to use one of the two  created Resource groups in the next module (creating VNET) but I keep encountering the following error:

> Error: Unsupported attribute
>
> on outputs.tf line 2, in output "RG":    2:   value       =
> [module.resourceGroups.resource_group_name]
>
> This value does not have any attributes.
>
> Unsupported attribute
>
> on terraformMain.tf line 33, in module "vnet":   33:
> resourcegroup_name = module.resourceGroups.resource_group_name[0]
>
> This value does not have any attributes.

The Azure Resource Group module code looks like this :

***main.tf***

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "RG" {
  name  = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.location
}
```

***variables.tf***

```
variable "location" {
    type = string
}

variable "resource_group_name" {
    type = string
}
```

***outputs.tf***

```
output "resource_group_names" {
   value       = concat(azurerm_resource_group.RG.*.name, [""])[0]
}
```

The code of the terraformMain.tf looks like this:

***terraformMain.tf***

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13"

  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "2.45.1"
    }
  }

  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name   = "__terraformresourcegroup__"
    storage_account_name  = "__terraformstorageaccount__"
    container_name        = "__terraformcontainer__"
    key                   = "__terraformkey__"
  }

}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

module "resourceGroups" {
  count     = length(var.resourcegroups)
  source    = "git::https://*****@dev.azure.com/****/TerraformAzureModules/_git/ResourceGroup"
  location  = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resourcegroups[count.index]
}

module "vnet" {
  source = "git::https://*****@dev.azure.com/****/TerraformAzureModules/_git/VirtualNetwork"
  resourcegroup_name = module.resourceGroups.resource_group_name[0]
  location = var.location  
  vnet_name = var.vnet_name

  count     = length(var.subnet_names)
  vnet_cidr = var.vnet_cidr[count.index]  
  subnet_cidr = var.subnet_cidr[count.index]
  subnet_name = var.subnet_names[count.index]
}
```

***variables.tf***

```
variable "location" {
    default = "westeurope" 
}

variable "resourcegroups" {
    default = ["rg1", "rg2"]
}

#Azure Vnet / Subnet
variable "vnet_name" {
  default = "vnet_1"
}
variable "subnet_names" {
  default = ["subnet1", "subnet2"]
}
variable "vnet_cidr" {
  default = ["10.116.15.0/24"]
}
variable "subnet_cidr" {
  default     = ["10.116.15.0/26", "10.116.15.128/27"]
}
```

***outputs.tf***

```
output "RG" {
  value       = [module.resourceGroups.resource_group_name]
}
```

any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you please share code of your module resourceGroups?

Comment: The code is already in the post, under " The Azure Resource Group module code looks like this"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution we have applied is to move the count from the terraformMain.tf to the resource module main.tf. this allowed us to pass the resoucgroups to the terraformMain through the output.tf of the module.

ResourceGroup module:

***main.tf***

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "RG" {
  count     = length(var.resource_group_name)
  name  = var.resource_group_name[count.index]
  location = var.location
}
```

***outputs.tf***

```
output "resource_group_names" {
   value       = azurerm_resource_group.RG.*.name
}
```

***terraformMain.tf code:***

```
    terraform {
      required_version = ">= 0.13"
    
      required_providers {
        azurerm = {
          source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
          version = "2.45.1"
        }
      }
    
      backend "azurerm" {
        resource_group_name   = "__terraformresourcegroup__"
        storage_account_name  = "__terraformstorageaccount__"
        container_name        = "__terraformcontainer__"
        key                   = "__terraformkey__"
      }
    
    }
    
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }
    
    module "resourceGroups" {
      source    = "git::https://*****@dev.azure.com/*****/TerraformAzureModules/_git/ResourceGroup"
      location  = var.location
      resource_group_name = var.resourcegroups
    }

module "vnet" {
  source = "git::https://******@dev.azure.com/*****/TerraformAzureModules/_git/VirtualNetwork"
  resourcegroup_name = module.resourceGroups.resource_group_names[0]
  location = var.location  
  vnet_name = var.vnet_name
  vnet_cidr = var.vnet_cidr 
  subnet_cidr = var.subnet_cidr
  subnet_name = var.subnet_names
}
```

I want to thank you for your contribution

Answer (score 2):

Your `resourceGroups` module has `count = length(var.resourcegroups)` set, and so `module.resourceGroups` is a list of objects and therefore you will need to request a specific element from the list before accessing an attribute:

```
module.resourceGroups[0].resource_group_name
```

Or, if your goal was to return a list of all of the resource group names, you can use [the `[*]` operator](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/splat.html) to concisely access the `resource_group_name` argument from each of the elements and return the result as a list:

```
resource.resourceGroups[*].resource_group_name
```

Answer (score 1):

The variables in the module need to have a `type` or a `default`.

For example, this would be a valid file:

```
variable "location" {
    type = string
}

variable "resource_group_name" {
    type = string
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. got the same error. The question has been updated with the most recent error message and code.